# Relationships with same foreign key to same table Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am building a referral system, the table *User* is referred by another, for example:

*User table:*

```
id

name
```

*Referrals table:*

```
id

referred_by (user_id)

refers_to (user_id)
```

Same foreign key to the same table. Which are the relationships between *User* table and *Referrals*?

Comment: It looks like you have a one-to-many (hasMany) for users-to-referrals, and one-to-one for referrals-to-users (hasOne). You'll have to create two relationships for both the users and the referrals, one pointing to the referred_by column, and one pointing to the refers_to column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your user model is `App\User` and your Referral model is `App\Referral`:

If you want to get, via your user, who they have referred you can do in `App\User`:

```
function  referredBy() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Referral', 'referred_by');
}
```

If you want to get, via your user, who they were referred by:

```
function referredTo() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Referral', 'refers_to');
}
```

Anywhere you have a `$user` object, you can get a list of all other referenced users by `$user->referredTo()` or `$user->referredBy()`
The Eloquent models allow you to create many different style relations with different key names.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit-ambiguous but if you want relationship in same table it can be done like this -

When building a table 'referrals_table' in the schema -

```
$table->foreign('refers_to')->references('referred_by')->on('referrals_table')
```

In the model the relationship will be (assuming name of this model file is ReferralTable)  -

```
public function name_your_function() {
    returns $this->belongsTo(ReferralTable::class)
}
```

You can call this function now to use it.